# Editor keeps complaining about bad aligned code block

Tags: bug, android-app

The editor keeps complaining about bad aligned code block and refusing to give me any hints, it's difficult to find an absent space, is there any better way to circumvent the nuisance?

Here's the code I tried to add in another question:

#### Third, review your products list that you just added

```
List<DoubleSales> products = productData.get(CustomerID);
for(DoubleSales product : products) {
    // access your product here.
}
```

And the screenshots:
[image]
[image]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Huawei
- Device Model: Nexus 6P

  - OS Version: 7.1.1 (3582057)

Comment: Can you show what you are trying, please. Even a screenshot could help.

Comment: @RoryAlsop updated

Comment: @ArtOfCode are you sure? Check out the code I paste in this question, you'll be surprised

Comment: @JerryChin he means blank line above the code block. You don't have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The editor is right, but it might be a little more informative when telling you *something* is wrong (a line number for example or the start of the alleged code block would be very useful).

This is the section at fault:

```
### Third, review your products list that you just added
    List<DoubleSales> products = productData.get(CustomerID);
    for(DoubleSales product : products) {
        // access your product here.
    }
```

The line break between the header and the code block is missing:

```
### Third, review your products list that you just added

    List<DoubleSales> products = productData.get(CustomerID);
    for(DoubleSales product : products) {
        // access your product here.
    }
```

The latter will render correctly. This behavior is the same on both the web site and the apps.